# Java, Validating Postal Code, Looping user Input

Tags: java, regex, validation

Hi and thank you for taking an interest into my question.

I'm writing a program that takes user input and writes it to a file. The program will prompt the user to enter personal information such as Name, Address, Province and Postal Code. I have 2 issues. The question ask's "How many customers information are you inputting" and I want to loop the amount of questions based on the users response. So if they say "5" the questions for name address etc, would all be looped for the 5 customers. Lastly, I don't know how I can validate the postal codes so that they are indeed, valid postal codes.

I saw lots of posts relating to validating Canadian Postal codes, but the posts just post the regex, but don't show how to actually implement it into a program.

What I came up with so far, as you can see I'm not very far because this is the beginning of my code, and since I need help with it, I can barely start.

```
package WritingToFiles;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CustomerList {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int customer;
    int loopAmount;
    customer = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many customers are you entering?: "));

    if (customer == amount entered) {
        //LOOP QUESTIONS ACCORDING TO AMOUNT ENTERED BY USER

      }



   }

}
```

I don't know how I can take the user input and based on what number they give, I can use it for the amount of times I'm going to ask them questions.

Heres what I tried to do in terms of the regex, no matter what I put I get invalid postal code.

```
public class CustomerList {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {



     String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the postal code: ");

            if (input.matches(" ^(?!.*[DFIOQU])[A-VXY][0-9][A-Z] ?[0-9][A-Z][0-9]$")) {
                System.out.println("Postal Code: " + input);
            } else {
                System.out.println("This postal code is invalid");
            }
```

Comment: Without seeing the actual code, this 'll be quite hard to reply on

Comment: Did you try anything at all? Provide what code you already have, what is working and what is not. Otherwise the question is not valid.

Comment: Lets step back: it sounds like you are a real beginner and don't know much about Java at all. And then you want to work on such a task; and you want us to help you ... like doing ... everything?

Comment: @Jägermeister No, I can do everything else if you can just help me with the 2 questions above

Comment: @Stultuske added code

Comment: You already wrote down a comment that says that you want to loop. Turn to the books, and lookup on "loops in java". Or turn to your favorite search engine. And same for the second thing - search for "java regex example" and you will find tons and tons of examples. Why do you think you need somebody explaining things to you that are wide out in the open? Alone the term "validation" is to fuzzy.

Comment: @Jägermeister

Like I said in the OP, I have searched, but they just give the regex, not actually how to use it in the program.

Comment: Strange. Maybe your search engine is broken. When i search for that three workds, I get a ton of links that contain example code. http://www.ocpsoft.org/opensource/guide-to-regular-expressions-in-java-part-1/ for starters

Comment: @Jägermeister check the OP, that is what I tried.

Comment: Ok so the regex works now, I don't know why it didn't before, but it works now. I will try and loop the user input shortly.

Answer (score -1):

For validating Postal Code I supouse that you should have the correct postal code information of the places where the software will be used and then compare the information provided with that to find any match. Hope this help.